# Как выполнить LogOff с помощью Java?

Tags: windows, java

Кто-нибудь знает, как можно с помощью сил java выполнить log off в ОС Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -l")
```

первая ссылка в гугле.

Answer (score 2):

Logoff зависит от оси, а Java платформенно-независима, так что единого рецепта нет, ну если не считать за таковую вызов команды оси из Java (как в ответе [@argamidon](/users/14145/argamidon))